# How to write a SQL query to manipulate data between 2 tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a use case to query 2 tables in a specific way.

Both tables have a single column.

Table 1 Column 1:

```
A
B
C
```

Table 2 Column 1:

```
1
2
3
```

I need to structure a query to get it to look like the following:

```
A 1
A 2
A 3
B 1
B 2
B 3
...
```

Is this possible in MS SQL Server?

Thanks,

Trent

Comment: look up `cross join`.

Comment: Use OUTER APPLY will give you exactly what you look for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called `CROSS JOIN`

```
Select t1.column1,t2.column1 from Table1 t1
CROSS JOIN Table2 t2
```

It will produce the Cartesian product between two tables.

Comment: Will not produce a Cartesian product because that is a set of ordered pairs. Is it useful to introduce an inappropriate mathematical term to newbys? The relational term is `product` (coined by Codd, who invented the relational model) and the SQL term is `CROSS JOIN` (as coined by ISO committee for SQL Standard).

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1 (normalized style):

```
  Select t1.column1,t2.column1 from Table1 t1 CROSS JOIN Table2 t2
```

Solution 2 (old style):

```
  Select t1.column1,t2.column1 from Table1 t1 , Table2 t2
```

Solution 3 (crazy style):

```
  Select t1.column1,t2.column1 from Table1 t1 inner join Table2 t2 on 1=1
```

My favorite is of course the cross join

Comment: (My opinion).  Not a great idea to mention obsolete join syntax (Solution 2), without mentioning that it's obsolete. Leaves impression to a newby that the syntax is equally acceptable.

Comment: not a obsolete syntax, just a different syntax, where have you read is obsolete?

Comment: i have modifed my proposition ;)

Comment: semantics! always a gotcha!  obsolete, antiquated, old style, etc. etc. my bad for not clarifying..  this syntax for joins is not considered best practice, and can generate wrong results in certain (primarily outer join) scenarios.  Newbys should be encouraged to use the newer SQL-92 join syntax.

Comment: Its not outer join, its cross join. But like all syntax if your query is bad, your result is wrong. Newbys should be encouraged to use the newer SQL-92 join syntax, sure,  AND know old syntax (some DBMS violating the SQL standard, sometime you work on old query). And old is different of obsolete. An example: select * from t1 , t2 where t1.cle *= t2.cle is an obsolte syntax for left outer join.

Comment: Everything you said is true, in fine details... but newbys often don't get the fine details, the intricacies, caveats, exceptions, etc. etc. on first read.  They should be encouraged, taught, led, influenced, exposed to, shown examples of, etc. etc. the new syntax which, when used, does not run as much risk of inappropriate usage by someone uneducated in all those fine details.  Cross join, outer join, inner join full join, I don't care, on this point, to me, in my opinion, (as I stated in first comment), that translates as obsolete.

Comment: @CharlesBretana: I agree with the 'know all the options, old and new, and make an informed choice' approach. We had a thread yesterday where it was deemed 'best practice' to rewrite `right outer join` to `left join`! Do you encourage people not to post `HAVING` because you can do without them it is confusing to newbys? Ditto nulls and three-valued logic? I know I do!

Comment: @onedaywhen,  if `having` and nulls, 3-valued logic were only part of SQL-89 syntax, and had been replaced with something more reliable, functional, less confusing, and easier to use in SQL-92, then yes, I would.  As to outer joins, I do make it a habit to try to only use `left join`s, and would encourage everyone to do so. I would *strongly encourage* everyone, newbies or experts, to avoid mixing `left` and `right outer join`s in the same query.

Comment: @CharlesBretana: Huh? We have always had an alternative to 3VL: Boolean logic and it didn't need replacing!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Tbl1.column1,Tbl1.column1 FROM Table1 Tbl1
CROSS JOIN Table2 Tbl2
ORDER BY Tbl1.column1
```